# ¿De que forma trasladar todos los paquetes de R de una instalación a otra?

Tags: r

El escenario es el siguiente: Tenemos funcionando `R` en un equipo desde hace un tiempo, hemos incorporado al entorno una cantidad relativamente grande de paquetes y ahora necesitamos migrar todos ellos a un nuevo equipo/entorno, ya sea por que:

- Hemos actualizado a una nueva versión de R
- Vamos a trabajar en otra computadora
- Vamos a migrar de sistema operativo

¿Hay una forma sencilla de copiar o instalar toda la paquetería de nuestro entorno actual al nuevo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los paquetes en general se van descargando y se descomprimen en una subcarpeta de `R` denominada `library`, uno podría pensar en copiar esta carpeta de un equipo a otro, cosa que podría funcionar en algunos casos, un cambio de versión de `R` por ejemplo (pero ejecutando luego: `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)`), pero al cambiar arquitectura o sistema operativo probablemente esta alternativa no sirva.

La forma más elegante de resolverlo (siempre que contemos con una conexión a internet) es: generando y salvando una lista de los paquetes de nuestro entorno actual, de la siguiente forma:

```
pkg.list <- installed.packages()[is.na(installed.packages()[ , "Priority"]), 1]
save(pkg.list, file="pkglist.Rdata")
```

Esto nos generará la lista en un archivo `pkglist.Rdata`, en el directorio actual de trabajo. Podemos llevarnos este archivo al nuevo equipo, a menos que solo se trate de un cambio de versión. Luego, sobre la nueva instalación de `R` cargamos este archivo y realizamos la instalación de los paquetes:

```
load("pkglist.Rdata")
install.packages(pkg.list)
```

Y simplemente tomarse un café y a esperar. Esto descargará los paquetes (versiones actualizadas) y realizará la instalación de cada uno. Tener en cuenta que en entornos Linux/OSX, muchos paquetes se "compilan" en el equipo y eventualmente podrían faltar dependencias, estos casos hay que ir resolviéndolos de forma manual.

fuente: [Migrating R libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133394/migrating-r-libraries)

Comment: Gracias por ir haciendo FAQs en SO (tiene harto tráfico SO) y ayudará a todos quienes comienzan a usar R y no están familiarizados con el inglés.

Comment: @jbkunst, sin duda, hay muy buen material en SO. Saludos